# Problem with "to_param" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page model that I want to find by a handle that I create from the title.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :title

  def to_param
    handle
  end

  def self.make_url_safe(string)
    handle = string.titleize.gsub(/ /,'').underscore.dasherize[0..35] 
    "#{handle}/" 
  end

end
```

In my controller, I have:

```
def show
    @page = Page.find_by_handle(params[:id])
 end
```

I'm doing the same thing with another model and it's working fine, but not with Page. I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
PagesController#show

Couldn't find Page with ID=test
```

Where `test` is the handle of the page. I feel like it was working just a few days ago when I created the model, so not sure what could've changed to cause the problem. Maybe the trailing `/`?

Here's the log:

```
Started GET "/pages/test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-28 11:53:49 -0400
  Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"test"}
  Page Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE ("pages"."id" = 0) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 12ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Page with ID=test):
```

Comment: It does seem like there is a before filter going one. Do you have anything set in the controller?

Comment: Cancan's `load_and_authorize` really loads data leading to this kind of errors.

Comment: Yeah, I do use CanCan. I remember now that I had that trouble with the other model.

Comment: FYI: Rails has `parameterize` which is basically for what you're trying to do with your bizzarre `titleize.underscore.dasherize` chain`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post an answer, though it was given in the comment above: CanCan interferes with `to_param` -- the solution is to authorize each resource in the controller, instead of using the generic `load_and_authorize_resources`.